# Instantclick is not defined on Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, instantclick.io

I try to integrate [instantclick](http://instantclick.io/) to my rails 6 application. I added the [instantclick.js file](http://instantclick.io/v3.1.0/instantclick.js) in my javascript/custom folder. Then, I import it in javascript/packs/application.js:

```
require("custom/instantclick")
```

I added to the end of the body tag of my layout the following line to initialize instantclick:

```
...
            <script data-no-instant>InstantClick.init();</script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Then, I get the following error in console:

> (index):404 Uncaught ReferenceError: InstantClick is not defined

I'm new to using webpacker, maybe I did something wrong. However, the instantclick.js file is imported. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack works differently than Sprockets. One thing you're running into is that webpack does not *expose* anything to the global scope. That means calling functions from a script tag won't work as expected unless you instruct webpack to add those variables to the `window` object.

Your instantclick.js file is also not module-aware, i.e, it does not *export* anything, such as with `module.exports = InstantClick`.

With webpack though, you can configure it to do both. You'll need to both *export* and *expose* `InstantClick`:

```
yarn add expose-loader exports-loader
```

```
// config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

environment.loaders.append('InstantClick', {
  test: /instantclick/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'expose-loader',
    options: 'InstantClick'
  },
    {
    loader: 'exports-loader',
    options: 'InstantClick'
  }]
})

module.exports = environment
```

There is more to learn and other ways you can do it of course. Here are some resources:

- https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/
- http://www.matthiassommer.it/programming/expose-global-variables-methods-modules-javascript/
- https://rossta.net/blog/three-ways-webpack-surprises-rails-developers.html

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I need to learn more about how webpacker works, I will read your documentation ;)